# Засунуть выбранные элементы в array | Jquery Js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, массивы, queryselector

Я выбрал элементы $(".itemimg") (их несколько) и хочу их положить в пустой список var items = []; Как это сделать правильно.

Comment: А как вы пытались это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если хочется прямо на ходу взять массив, в jQuery есть метод `.toArray()`

```
var items = $(".itemimg").toArray();
```

При этом в массив попадут именно ссылки на HTML-объекты, не jQuery-объекты. Т.е. методы jQuery перестанут работать для элементов массива.

Аналог на современном JS ([оператор Spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)):

```
let items = [...document.querySelectorAll(".itemimg")]
```

---

Если массив создается где-то в другом месте и нужно именно добавить туда элементы, можно использовать обычный перебор:

```
var items = [];
/* много кода */
$(".itemimg").each(function() {
  items.push(this);
});
```

Это эквивалент предыдущего варианта...
Если хочется добавить в массив jQuery-объекты, можно записать `.push( $(this) )`, тогда все методы jQuery будут работать для каждого отдельного элемента.

---

P.s. хак: `var items = $(".itemimg").toArray().map($);`

Что делает `map()` ? Вызывает переданную функцию для каждого элемента массива и подменяет этот элемент на результат вызова функции. А `$` - это как-раз функция) Поэтому `.map($)` оборачивает все элементы в jQuery - объекты)

Comment: `querySelectorAll` и так возвращает массив, зачем там `Spread` ?

Comment: @MoloF возвращает список элементов, в который для удобства встроили метод `forEach`... а других методов массива у него нет. Там... map, reduce, filter.

Comment: Спасибо за просвещение, не знал что он урезан и даже никогда об этом не думал